# Creating folder and adding multiple images

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I'm creating an iPhone app where I need to create separate folder and add images in those folder and upload that whole folder on google drive. How can i create folder and images to it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing,were you able to do this? And how did you do that? I am able to create directory and inside that files but not able to get the entire content of folder at once. I am getting the list of files though but want to get the entire content and send to server at one call.Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Creating A Folder**

```
        NSString  *pngPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/WB/%@",self.viewIndex]];

        // Check if the directory already exists
        BOOL isDir;        
        BOOL exists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pngPath isDirectory:&isDir];
        if (exists) 
        {
            if (!isDir) 
            {
                NSError *error = nil;
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager]  removeItemAtPath:pngPath error:&error];
                // Directory does not exist so create it
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:pngPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Directory does not exist so create it
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:pngPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
        }
```

**Adding Images to that Folder**

```
    NSString  *pngImagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/WB/%@/%d.png",self.viewIndex,lineIndex]];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    self.curImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.curImage) writeToFile:pngImagePath atomically:YES];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: @"/WB/%@" is folder name??

Comment: WB is folderName and inside that all images will be there. @arshad

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

//For save to Document Directory

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *theDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:now];
NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];

NSString *strImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/MyPhotos/Dt%@%@.png",theDate,theTime];
strImageName=[strImageName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
strImageName=[strImageName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];

[self createDocumentDirectory:@"MyPhotos"];
NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory()  stringByAppendingPathComponent:strImageName];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(YourImageView.image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];





    -(void)createDocumentDirectory:(NSString*)pStrDirectoryName
    {
        NSString *dataPath = [self getDocumentDirectoryPath:pStrDirectoryName];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:NULL];
    }

    -(NSString*)getDocumentDirectoryPath:(NSString*)pStrPathName
    {
NSString *strPath = @"";
        if(pStrPathName)
            strPath = [[kAppDirectoryPath objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:pStrPathName];

        return strPath;
    }

   //Get Photo Onebyone


    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[self getDocumentDirectoryPath:@"MyPhotos"] error:&error];

    if (!error) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.png'"];
        NSArray *imagesOnly = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        for (int i=0;i<[imagesOnly count]; i++) {
            [arrSaveImage addObject:[imagesOnly objectAtIndex:i]];//Save in your array.
        }
    }
```